# Creating a linear model / regression where all data is factors / given in proportion (data included)

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(Proportion = c(0.1,0.15,0.22,0.20,0.29,0.37,0.41,0.36, 0.47,0.67),
                 Age  = c("15-20", "20-25", "25-30", "30-35", "35-40", "40-45", 
                          "45-50", "50-55", "55-60", "60-65"))
plot(df$Proportion, ylab = "Proportion")
```

[image: Propotion vs Age]

From the plot the Proportion seems to be increasing with Age. What is the correct way to create a to model out of this data to see how Proportion increases with Age? To somewhat also distinguish the difference of proportion between a 15 year old and a 20 year old. Age is assumed to be contionous.

If someone knows articles or books that covers this problem, please let me know as I searched, but not found anything. In my original data set I also have number of observations within each group.

Comment: You write example data and that both are factors. (1) Proportion is a factor? is doesn't seem to be (o need to be). (2) Did you group Age for the sake of brevity here, or is it clumped up like that in the data (i.e., 15-20 and not 15,16,17..)

Comment: You are correct, it is not a factor. The age is grouped is grouped in the data set. Although, I could go back to the original source and extract it non-grouped.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is this. If indeed you can extract the age in a continuous format it might prove advantageous:

1. The data is more robust.
2. The way it is currently created makes it ambiguous when 20, 25 etc.. are, as they belong to two groups simultaneously.
3. *caveat* - If there is a logical or theoretical reason to group Age, than do so. For example, if certain Age points hold specific meaning, like 21 (drinking age), 65 (pension), 6 (entering elementary school) or otherwise, than grouping *is* what you want to do.

Now, if you have two interval variables (`Proportion` and `Age`), I would plot them to see the connection visually. Since these are only two variables (no other controls), There is no real need for regression (Ill go there in a sec). 
--Note that the below is resting on a linear connection (which seems the case with your data)

**You can measure the correlation (Pearson's $r$)**:

```
> cor.test(df$Proportion,df$Age)

Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  df$Proportion and df$Age
t = 8.4717, df = 8, p-value = 2.884e-05
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.7917609 0.9880651
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.9485315
```

This means that the connection ($r=0.949$) between the two variables is very **very** strong (and significant). With a $95%$ chance, the correlation in the actual population is between $0.791$ and $0.988$

**Regressing these:**

```
> summary(lm(Proportion~Age, data=df))

Call:
lm(formula = Proportion ~ Age, data = df)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.097030 -0.032030  0.009212  0.018409  0.106545 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -0.075091   0.050445  -1.489    0.175    
Age          0.010642   0.001256   8.472 2.88e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.05705 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8997,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8872 
F-statistic: 71.77 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 2.884e-05
```

This enables you to talk about the relation in actual terms: Age's coefficient ($0.01$) means that every increase in one year in Age, raises the average predicted Proportion by $0.01$. $R^2=0.899$ means that Age explains $89.9%$ of the variance in Proportion.

If you want to plot it with the regression line (using `ggplot2` here):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Age, y=Proportion)) + geom_point(size=4) + geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

[image]

Comment: I my example I meant for example age 15-20 is above 15 and below 20, so 20 will not be in two groups. The problem with using age is:

Comment: If data is small, the age proportion within every group has a high variance. Some ages is missing.

Comment: That shouldn't matter much, Many variables are continuous but without representatives of every value

Comment: If age is grouped, you should use Spearman rank correlation. Also, proportions should not be modeled with OLS regression, in particular if some values are close to zero or one.